# Search Function that Shows 8 results at a time in C

Tags: c

Im setting up a Recursive Search Function that i want displays the first 8 Results then (when chosen) shows the next 8 Results

Heres my Search Function

```
static int Search(char *path, const char *file) {
    DIR *dir;


    char *slash = "/";

    int ret = 1;

    struct dirent *entry;

    if ((dir = opendir(path)) == NULL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {



        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        //we check if the path has already a / if not we add one

        int length = strlen(path);

        if (path[length - 1] != '/') {
            slash = "/";
        }

        length += strlen(entry->d_name) + 2;
        char *newpath = malloc(length);
        if (!newpath) {
            break;
        }

        snprintf(newpath, length, "%s%s%s", path, slash, entry->d_name);

        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, file) == 0) {
            printf("Was found here %s Search Successful\n", newpath);

/* Entries here Show Only 8 First 8 then later show the Next 8 results*/

            ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;
            break;
        }

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
            Search(newpath, file);
        else {
            free(newpath);
            continue;
        }

        free(newpath);
    }
    if (closedir(dir) != 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: Is there an issue here? Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and tell us what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Would "visitor" pattern be used? Instead of returning found paths, to pass paths to a callback one by one, then callback could count until 8

Comment: Note:your path/len/slash logic can be done before the loop.